# When I run the pip command via cmd, I get an error

Tags: python, pip

I want to download a module by typing 'pip install pygame' on cmd. But I am getting syntax error. I'm not in the python compiler either. I tried all the solutions on the internet. I'm still getting the same error. If I type 'pip --version' it's the same. how can i overcome this problem. You can see the error screenshot in below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qiQW.png)

Comment: Please copy-and-paste your error message into the question, rather than using an image. If you submit it as an image, it makes it hard for answerers to google the error message.

Comment: I think is better to install inside a virtualenv
`python -m venv env` and then `env\Scripts\activate.bat`
install: `pip install pygame`

Comment: This error indicates that someone tried to put a version of pip intended for Python 3.6 or above, into your Python 3.5 installation. It's a good time to update Python anyway, as you're quite out of date: 3.10.0 is expected to have its final release in a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

The "`f`" syntax has been introduced in Python 3.6, while you're running on Python 3.5

Use a more recent version of Python.